# Can I clone a larger disk with lots of free space into a smaller disk

Tags: linux, hard-disk, file-copy, cloning

Is it possible to clone an OS disk with all its partitions into a smaller disk.

The original disk has a lot of free space and the total used space is much smaller than the capacity of the new disk I am trying to create.

I want to do this without tinkering with the original hard disk

Comment: what you mean `has a lot of free space`? unpartitioned one?

Comment: I mean the largest partition has lots of free space

Comment: You are looking for "Ghost" utility of windows. https://www.symantec.com/products/theme/ghost?id=ghost

Comment: Unlike windows (which can fail to boot if certain system files are moved around), linux does not care at all where ANY of the files on the disk are located.  `cp`, `rsync`, `tar`, and many other commands can be used to copy a filesystem from one partition to another.  If you want the disk to be bootable, you'll have to run grub-install.

Answer (score 0):

You could partition your new disk drive to make enough room for files for each source partition you have. Then boot into single user mode and copy files with `tar` from original partitions to their 'mirrors' one by one:

```
cd /source/mount/point; tar --one-file-system cf -|tar -C /mirror/mount/point xf -
```

add `--acls`, `--selinux` and/or `--xattrs` options to the 'archiving' `tar` in the command pipe if appropriate. You would need also to set up a boot loader on your new drive and adjust `/etc/fstab` file to match labels/uuids/device names